# Loop through a set of variables based on condition in another variable

Tags: stata

I have a list of variables `a_23  a_24_1  a_24_2  a_24_3  a_24_4  a_24_5  a_24_6  a_24_7  a_24_8`.

The values in variables `a_24*` are based on the response in `a_23`.
If `a_23==1`, then at least one variable in `a_24*` must be equal to 1.

I therefore want to check if any of the variables `a_24*` does not contain the value 1 if `a_23==1`

I tried the loop below,

```
foreach var of varlist a_24_1* {
    br a_23 a_24* if a_23==1 & `var' != 1
}
```

but it returns all the variables that do not contain 1 in the set of variables. However, I only need cases where all variables do not contain the value 1 if the determining variable is equal to 1.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not do your homework for you. At least show some effort. What have you tried?

Comment: foreach var of varlist a_24_1*  {
br a_23 a_24* if a_23 == 1 & `var' != 1
}

Comment: Looks like you missed something. Visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for some guidelines about asking on Stackoverflow. First - don't put your code and other relevant details in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: This loop  returns all the variables that do not contain 1 in the set of variables. However, I only need cases where all variables do not contain the value 1 if the determining variable is equal to 1

Comment: Thanks @svgrafov , let me check that again

Answer (score 0):

A data example as well as code would be a good idea, so that you then base your question on an MCVE: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for explanation.

As I understand it an intermediate variable would help here:

```
egen mina_24 = rowmin(a_24_*)
```

as the minimum will be 0 if and only if all values are 0.

Note that your loop

```
foreach var of varlist a_24_1* { 
    br a_23 a_24* if a_23 == 1 & `var' != 1 
}
```

is a loop over the single variable `a_24_1`; presumably you mean `a24_*` in the `foreach` line.